# is it possible to detect when any application is in full screen in android?

Tags: android, view

I would like to know if there is some sort of way using maybe views or something to have a background service detect if the foreground app is in full screen or not. meaning the status bar is hidden or not hidden.

I was thinking maybe using constant strings to detect if a view is shown or not? But im not sure exactly. Root is an option if needed.

Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about using a broadcast receiver or something like that. That would be ideal, however there is no such broadcast for a full screen request.

Here is what I did do however.

I created an invisible overlay, this invisible overlay is 0 x 0 in size :)

I then use `View.getLocationOnScreen(int[]);`

This returns the int array with the values of the coordinates in x and y. I then test these coordinates (only really focusing on the y value) if it equals 0, then the current viewable activity is in full screen, (because it is at the highest most area on the screen) if the status bar is showing, then the view will return with (50 pixels on my device) meaning the view is 50 pixels from the top of the screens edge.

I place all this in a service which has a timer and when the timer expires, it gets the location, runs the tests, and does what I need to do. The timer is then cancelled when the screen shuts off. Upon screen on, timer is restarted.

I checked how much CPU it uses, and it says 0.0% in System Tuner.

Comment: This seems like a good solution to this issue, just what I've been looking for, thanks for sharing :)

Comment: How would you go about creating such an invisible overlay?

Answer (score 3):

I like the idea of Seth, so I made the code snippet:

```
/**
 * Check if fullscreen is activated by a position of a top left View
 * @param topLeftView View which position will be compared with 0,0
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isFullscreen(View topLeftView) {
    int location[] = new int[2];
    topLeftView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    return location[0] == 0 && location[1] == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `getWindow().getAttributes().flags`?

```
public static boolean fullScreen = (getWindow().getAttributes().flags & WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN) != 0;
public static boolean forceNotFullScreen = (getWindow().getAttributes().flags & WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN) != 0;
public static boolean actionbarVisible = getActionBar().isShowing();
```

Reference:

```
if( MyActivity.fullScreen){
      // full screen
}
else{
     // not full screen
}
```

Comment: This would work with my own activity. However, how can i get the attributes of another's activity?? Thanks for the reply @LazyNinja

Comment: You have choices to access it from a service by either using static variable or using application. Lets say public static boolean fullScreen; And in your service you refer to it like this MyActivity.fullScreen . Or you can use an application to store the status of all the activities. SharedPreferences also is another way to share between services and activities.

Comment: Im not exactly sure you are understanding my question :P lol. Let me give a real example. 

Say i start up a game, and that game is in full screen and i can no longer see the status bar, i want my service to detect that the status bar is not visible and to then execute some code. Once the user leaves the game and the status bar is visible, i want to execute some more code. 

Hope i cleared things up! Thanks again for your response @LazyNinja!